# Bean with many fields

Tags: design-patterns, javabeans, dao

I am currently adding functionality to a project that currently passes a Java object into a Drools rules engine. The next phase of work involves adding new fields to the data object. This will result in the data object containing in excess of 30 fields. Is there a better way of implementing this as this seems rather inelegant.

Thanks

Angus

Comment: KISS first, patterns later.

Comment: "_better way of implementing..._" is a broad and subjective question. There is no way to answer that other than generalized guessing. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on formulating a good question.